# MySQL database (8.0.30) - Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) - Error on stored procedure and cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor, mysql-error-1241

I'm struggling with a MySQL 1241 "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error.

This is a test stored procedure. I cannot figure out where's the problem. I'm learning MySQL, thanks!

```
DECLARE c_Property_URL varchar(250) DEFAULT ""; 
DECLARE finished int DEFAULT 0;

-- declare cursor for property URL
DECLARE curPropertyURL CURSOR FOR SELECT URL FROM `dbmaster`.`KIC_TB_Property`;
-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
OPEN curPropertyURL;
    getPropertyURL: LOOP
    FETCH curPropertyURL INTO c_Property_URL;
        SELECT ('property URL is: ',c_Property_URL);
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getPropertyURL;
        END IF;
    END LOOP getPropertyURL;
CLOSE curPropertyURL;
```

Comment: Please show ALL the error message

Comment: # Time Action Message Duration / Fetch
0 1 14:17:53 CALL `dbmaster`.`test`() Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) 0.328 sec

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using tuple syntax in your select-list:

```
SELECT ('property URL is: ',c_Property_URL);
```

I assume you intended this to be string concatenation, but this is not MySQL's syntax for string concatenation. If you want that, use:

```
SELECT CONCAT('property URL is: ',c_Property_URL);
```

Tuple syntax is allowed in some SQL expressions, but not for scalar expressions in the select-list.

Comment: that was the problem! thank you very much!!!